# Android listarray global variable

Tags: java, android, arrays, global-variables, lifecycle

I've got an activity than can start\stop my service. In service there is alarmManager that every x min starts my BroadcastReceiver.
I need to keep some data in ArrayList from every BroadcastReceiver and use (add/remove) it another time in next BroadcastReceiver. I tried create static ArrayList in my service, but when i stop (restart) it - i lose my data. And when I again start my main activity - i lose data because of life cycle...

So i need global arraylist accessible in BroadcastReceiver. And this array should be avaible all time from onBoot event until phone die ;)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a database for your data, read from it at start and write to it at stop. The Andorid tutorial goes through how to handle a database.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create your static array outside of your service for example in a new class.

Comment: static variable in a service class is exactly the same as in any other class. it he said the data was lost, it means a new vm has started

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you stop - you don't terminate the vm - only `finish()` the activity.
If you need persistence, go for shared preferences (easiest), or database.